# Return int or string from C++ function exposed to Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

Using Boost Python, is it possible for a C++ function exposed to python to return either an integer or a string (or other type) depending on the *value* of the single argument passed in?

So in Python I want to do this:

```
from my_module import get_property_value     

# get an integer property value
i = get_property_value("some_int_property")

# get a string 
s = get_property_value("some_string_property")
```

C++ pseudo code (obviously won't it work like this, but you get the idea)

```
???? getPropertyValue(const char* propertyName)
{
  Property *p = getProperty(propertyName);
  switch(p->type)
  {
    case INTEGER: return p->as_int();
    case STRING: return p->as_string();
    ...
  }
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
  boost::python::def("get_property_value", &getPropertyValue);
}
```

If it makes any difference, I'm using Boost 1.48 with Python 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the C++ function return a [`boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#object-spec-ctors).  The `object` constructor will attempt to 
converts its argument to the appropriate python type and manages a reference to it.  For example, `boost::python::object(42)` will return a Python object with a Python type of `int`.

---

Here is a basic example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Get value, returning a python object based on the provided type
///        string.
boost::python::object get_value(const std::string& type)
{
  using boost::python::object;
  if      (type == "string") { return object("string 42"); }
  else if (type == "int")    { return object(42);          }
  return object(); // None
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("get_value", &get_value);
}
```

and its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> x = example.get_value("string")
>>> x
'string 42'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> x = example.get_value("int")
>>> x
42
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> x = example.get_value("")
>>> x
>>> type(x)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: tks, boost::python::object saves my day

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you make the C++ function return an `object`. It will have to do the appropriate conversions internally.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
string getPropertyValue(cont char* propertyName)
{
    // do some stuff
    if (someCondition)
    {
        return "^" + someInteger;
    }
    else
    {
        return someString; // if someString starts with the character '^', make
                           // it start with "^^" instead.
    }
}
```

Then in Python, if the return value doesn't start with `"^"`, use it as-is as a string.  Otherwise if it starts with `"^^"`, trim one of them off and then use it as a string.  Otherwise trim the one `"^"` off the beginning and use it as an int.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this in c (or c++). Worse, you're trying to use a function pointer - which means you can't even overload.

What you can do is build a *Property* ***Class*** with methods for property->as_int() and property->as_string();